# In Firebird can you use a cursor with EXECUTE STATEMENT?

Tags: stored-procedures, cursor, firebird, firebird2.1

I would like to pass, to a stored procedure, a table and field name, and then do a FOR SELECT on the table and, for some records, change the field value. I just learned about cursors which is a very convenient way to make changes in a FOR SELECT loop. But can I use cursors with EXECUTE STATEMENT?

I want this stored procedure to work for a variety of tables with a similar structure so I want it to be generic hence passing in the table name and field name.

I'm pretty sure the answer is "No." so how could I do this?

Comment: `AS CURSOR` is not supported in `FOR EXECUTE STATEMENT` loops, even if the statement to execute is a suitable SELECT query.

Comment: See the Firebird language reference: [`FOR EXECUTE STATEMENT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql-coding.html#fblangref25-psql-forexec), but you can't do positioned updates that way.